# Setting app icon in electron using electron forge and react ( typescript ) stack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I've setup an electron app with
[TS+Webpack](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template)
and
[React TS](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react-with-typescript)

I'm trying to change the app icon.

I have the following folder structure for the app

```
src
    ├───main
    │   ├───assets
    │   ├───methods
    │   └───types
    |   index.ts
    |   preload.ts
    ├───renderer
    │   ├───assets
    │   ├───components
    │   ├───context
    │   ├───helpers
    │   ├───layout
    │   ├───mui
    │   ├───router
    │   └───views
    └───typings
```

the icon is placed in `src/main/assets` folder, inside the index.ts ( main process file )
I've added

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 800,
    width: 1200,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/64x64.png'),
})
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Other than that, I have the following webpack config in `webpack.rules.js` for image files, which is used to import image files in the renderer.

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|jp2|webp)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'images/[name].[ext]'
    }
  }
```